# Make a tree structure from a path name

Tags: python, dictionary

This might be very simple, but I'm not sure what to do here.
In Python, I want to go through a list like:

```
full_list = ["A/A/A", "A/A/B", "B/B/B", "A/C/B"]
```

and get a dictionary with a kind of tree structure based on these labels, like this:

```
dictionary = {"A:{"A":["A", "B"], "C":["B"]},"B":{"B":["B]}}
```

but I'm not sure how to do it. I realize that I need some nested for loops. I know about the split() function in Python.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: Do you know that all inputs will have the same "depth?"  All your examples are 3 deep, but is it possible you'd need to process something like `"A/B"`?  What would the result, specifically `dictionary["A"]` look like?  A dictionary or a list?

Comment: Yes, all examples will be of depth 3.

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion with `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def to_tree(data):
   d = defaultdict(list)
   for a, *b in data:
      d[a].append(b)
   return {a:[i for [i] in b] if all(len(i) == 1 for i in b) else to_tree(b)  
           for a, b in d.items()}

full_list = ["A/A/A", "A/A/B", "B/B/B", "A/C/B"]
result = to_tree([i.split('/') for i in full_list])
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'A': ['A', 'B'], 'C': ['B']}, 'B': {'B': ['B']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the leaf nodes list entries instead of empty dictionaries makes this trickier IMO -- I'd rethink that aspect of it.

```
>>> full_list = ["A/A/A", "A/A/B", "B/B/B", "A/C/B"]
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dictionary = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
>>> for entry in full_list:
...     node = dictionary
...     for path in entry.split("/"):
...         if isinstance(node, dict):
...             node = node[path]
...         else:
...             node.append(path)
...
>>> dictionary
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000001C8098171F0>, {'A': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': ['A', 'B'], 'C': ['B']}), 'B': defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'B': ['B']})})
```